# Fixed-point properties for affine actions of topological groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, banach-spaces, topological-groups, fixed-point-theorems, amenability

T. Mitchell [[Illinois J. Math. 14 (1970) 630--641](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256052955)] defined four properties of a topological semigroup, and in particular of a topological group $G$.
Two of them are:

(F2)  Every jointly continuous affine action of $G$ on a compact convex set has a common fixed point.

(F4)  Every separately continuous affine action of $G$ on a compact convex set has a common fixed point.

**Question:** Is there a topological group that satisfies (F2) but not (F4)?

It is known that (F2) and (F4) are equivalent when the group $G$ is locally compact or completely metrizable.
For locally compact $G$ this is proved by Mitchell,
for locally compact or completely metrizable by Berglund, Junghenn and Milnes, "Analysis on semigroups", Theorem 5.7 in Chapter 4.